# Return rows based on the max value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of results like this, where the usage of each item totals 100%:

| Item | Usage | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 90 | Customer 1 |
| Item1 | 10 | Customer 2 |
| Item2 | 54 | Customer 3 |
| Item2 | 46 | Customer 2 |
| Item3 | 23 | Customer 4 |
| Item3 | 77 | Customer 5 |

From this, I want to only show the rows with the max usage of each item, to show the customer that used the most of the item, so my results would be:

| Item | Usage | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 90 | Customer 1 |
| Item2 | 54 | Customer 3 |
| Item3 | 77 | Customer 5 |

I've tried using max and group by, but I can't seem to get it to return only the max usage rows, I always end up with all 6 rows due to the need to include the customer column. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can allow the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window function to craft a ranking value for each of your items, ordered by usage. Then make [`TOP(1) WITH TIES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) filter values with respect to the `ORDER BY` clause, getting only the first value tied (row number = 1, or if you will, the greatest usage value for each item).

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES *
FROM tab 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Item] ORDER BY [Usage] DESC)
```

Equivalently, you can compute the `ROW_NUMBER` window function first, then select all rows that have ranking = 1 in a subquery.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Item] ORDER BY [Usage] DESC) AS rn
    FROM tab 
)
SELECT [Item], [Usage], [Customer]
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Output**:

| Item | Usage | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 90 | Customer 1 |
| Item2 | 54 | Customer 3 |
| Item3 | 77 | Customer 5 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NtQIaRKJ).

Consider learning more about these SQL-Server tools at the corresponding linked web pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have used data provided by you to create a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3205dd/5).

> I want to only show the rows with the max usage of each item, to show
> the customer that used the most of the item.

This can be achieved as

```
select t1.item, t1.usage, t1.customer
from table1 t1
inner join (
  select item, MAX(usage) as maximum_usage
  from table1
  group by item
) t2 on t1.usage = t2.maximum_usage;
```

This gives me the expected output as :

| item | usage | customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 90 | Customer 1 |
| Item2 | 54 | Customer 3 |
| Item3 | 77 | Customer 5 |

You can see the demo in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3205dd/5)